# What is the difference between "Lock screen", "Badge" and "Pop-up" notifications

Tags: samsung, notifications, samsung-one-ui

I just got a new Samsung A54 and I'm trying to set it's notifications to "preserve my sanity" mode.

In Settings > Notifications > App notifications, I can select individual app. On the App notification screen, I can then:

- Allow/disallow notifications
- Set allowed ones to "Allow sound and vibration" or "Silent"
- Under "Notification types" I can select **"Lock screen", "Badge" and/or "Pop-up"** (latter only if sound and vibrations are allowed.

I have some idea what each of the notification types means, but would like some clarification. Screenshots with examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.